# Reducing build pipeline time using parallel keyword in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

I am trying to reduce the the Gitlab pipeline execution time, by running multiple thread for a job using “parallel: 4” keyword in one of my bottleneck build job. With this I can see that my job as 4 threads with name like 1/4 to 4/4, but the execution is not parallel, they execute sequentially, can someone help me understand why this is happening and any other way to reduce the build time by running things in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky question to answer - because the best answer is it depends.

Also the [documentation about the Parallel Directive](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#parallel-matrix-jobs) states

> Jobs can only run in parallel if there are multiple runners, or a single runner is configured to run multiple jobs concurrently.

Additionally it is also mentioned here again https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#use-your-own-runners

1. Do you run your own runners or do you use shared runners?

   The runners must be configured to allow concurrent execution, if they are not configured like that, you will not be able to run jobs in parallel. With own runners you might be able to change this.

   > concurrent: limits how many jobs globally can be run concurrently. The most upper limit of jobs using all defined runners. 0 does not mean unlimited
2. What is the limit of parallel execution on the runner?

   Besides the `concurrent` setting there is also the limit settings on the runner.

   > limit: Limit how many jobs can be handled concurrently by this token. 0 (default) simply means don’t limit.

All this information about runners can be checked at the [GitLab Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-global-section)

Comment: Interesting, changing the concurrent setting helped me, but still there are other errors I am trying to solve. Luckily for now changing the Cloud VM region helped a lot to reduce the run time. Thanks @simon-schrottner